# Search an array for a string to get its index in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I want to search an array for a string and get its index number.

```
li = ["New Year's Day", 'Lohri', 'Pongal', 'Makar Sankranti', 'Guru Govind Singh Jayanti', 'Republic Day', 'Chinese New Year', "Valentine's Day", 'Vasant Panchami', 'Shivaji Jayanti']
```

So what should I write to make it return the index number
like I call a faction `check = checkindex('Pongal')` and this should return 2.
How do I write this function.

Comment: you mean *list*. In which case, just `li.index(word)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate function for that

```
li.index('Pongal')
```

Comment: i am new to python. Thx